# Transform XML node

Tags: xml, xslt, vbscript

I've created the following XML node + childnodes via VBScript and I'm adding it to an existing XML document.

```xml
<list name="Info">
    <item name="ViewName">Page</item>
    <item name="DBField">Text</item>
    <item name="Type">String</item>
</list>
```

But in the XML document, the node is inserted in 1 single line:

```xml
<list name="Info"><item name="ViewName">Page</item><item name="DBField">Text</item><item name="Type">String</item></list>
```

I've done some research about XSLT but I can't figure out how to transform my node properly or create a proper template.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: The application that reads the created xml file, needs line breaks after each list/item

Comment: Then the real problem is with the target application. Perhaps it would be better to spend the effort on fixing that. In any case, if you want help with your XSLT code, then show us the code, along with a small example of the XML input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "pretty-printing". A possible solution for VBScript is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2012/07/06/creating-quot-pretty-quot-xml-using-xsl-and-vbscript.aspx) by Robert McMurray. In a nutshell:

```vb
inFile  = "C:\path\to\input.xml"
outFile = "C:\path\to\output.xml"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
Set xsl = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

' Put whitespace between tags. (Required for XSL transformation.)
txt = fso.OpenTextFile(inFile).ReadAll
txt = Replace(txt, "><", ">" & vbCrLf & "<")

' Create an XSL stylesheet for transformation.
stylesheet = _
  "<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">" & _
  "<xsl:output method=""xml"" indent=""yes""/>" & _
  "<xsl:template match=""/"">" & _
  "<xsl:copy-of select="".""/>" & _
  "</xsl:template>" & _
  "</xsl:stylesheet>"

' Transform the XML.
xsl.loadXML stylesheet
xml.loadXML txt
xml.transformNode xsl
xml.save outFile
```